# Having DataContractSerializer serialize the same class in two different ways?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm using the DataContractSerializer to serialize an objects properties and fields marked with DataMember attributes to xml.

Now a have another use case for the same class, where I need to serialize other properties and other fields.

Are there a way to add "another DataMemberAttribute" that can be used for my other serialization scenario?

Comment: It could be argued that if you need to serialize different properties and fields, that it's not actually the same class.

Comment: I disagree.  If the same class is implementing multiple interfaces, certain data elements may be relevant to only one of the interfaces.

Comment: Interfaces are sets of behaviors. What gets serialized is state. If you have two sets of state, then you have two classes.

Comment: @John Saunders: Yes, I follow you, but it's the same state that is serialized twice, but with two different "security levels", so that the consumer is restricted from certain data in certain use cases. More specifically this is a business object, that in certain cases need to be serialized with it's references to other business objects, and in other cases doesn't.

Comment: Have you considered teaching your objects about security levels?  That way the object could return a null/0/empty value when you read the property with insufficient clearance.

Comment: @all: Sorry for the late reply, I've been away for the weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, basically.

If you want to use the existing `DataContractSerializer`, you'll have to maintain a second version of the DTO class and convert the data between them.

Options if you are writing your own serialization code:

- declare your own `[DataMember]`-style attribute(s) and interpret them at runtime in your own serialization code
- use a "buddy class"
- use external metadata (such as a file)
- use code-based configuration (i.e. via a DSL)

In reality, I expect the first will be the simplest choice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Writing my own serialization code could be an option, but I really wouldn't know where to start - I'm using both DataContractSurrogate and are preserving references, and it seems like it takes some effort to "simulate" the behavior of the DataContractSerializer. Is there a way to write one based on the existing DataContractSerializer or are there links to similar solutions that your know of?

Comment: The whole set of built in serialization techniques are such a tease.  They look like they do what you want right up until you try and do something useful with them.  I actually prefer the XAML serialization format because at least it does pretend to be anything other a XML based format of an object graph.

Comment: @Darrel Miller: Thanks for the pointer to XAML serialization format. I will check that out.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar scenario in the past, we've taken an Object Oriented approach, and created a new class that extends from the main class.
To help you achieve inhertience with the DataContractSerializer, check out [KnownTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx)

In one of your comments to your question,

> If the same class is implementing multiple interfaces, certain data elements may be relevant to only one of the interfaces.

If that is the case in your scenario, then perhaps your Data Service Contracts should be exposing just the Interfaces, and not the Class?

For example, if you have a class like:

```
[DataContract]
public class DataObject : IRed, IBlue
```

then rather than have your operation contract expose DataObject, you have two operation contracts one for IRed and one for IBlue.
This eliminates the need for custom serialization code.

Comment: I think you are very right about that last point. The only downside to it, is that there will be a lot of duplicate "declaration" of properties in the interfaces, as most of the properties are serialized in both situations.

Comment: Ah well, duplicate declarations are no big deal... it's not the same as duplicate code logic, in my view.

Comment: I agree! But it is kind of tedious keeping them in sync... but well the compiler will of course help me there, and I shouldn't be so lazy :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it, but it's an ugly hack.

The `DataContractSerializer` can serialize objects that implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface. You could implement the interface and create your own `ReadXml(XmlReader reader)` and `WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)` methods that could serialize the object in different ways.

Note that you'd have to have a flag embedded within the class itself to determine which way to serialize the object. (There's no way to tell the `DataContractSerializer` which mode to use, so the flag has to be contained in the object itself.)

A second version of the DTO class, as @Marc suggests, would be much cleaner.